# Trying to use the latest price data using Chainlink in Remix it throws me an error

Tags: solidity, blockchain, chainlink

Hello iam trying to get the latest price data using Chainlink Data Feeds but it throws this error :

```
pragma solidity 0.7.6;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "contracts/Token.sol";


contract DonateContract {
AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;
address payable owner; // contract creator's address


constructor() {

priceFeed = 
AggregatorV3Interface(0x2514895c72f50D8bd4B4F9b1110F0D6bD2c97526);
owner = payable(msg.sender); // setting the contract creator
```

}

```
function donate(uint256 _payAmount) public payable  {

(bool success,) = owner.call{value: _payAmount}("");
 require(success, "Failed to send money");
 CRON token = CRON(0x2F718Bc4390F8662bB664D1FDd88494ac6bE71eC);
 uint256 cost =  _payAmount * 6 * priceFeed.latestRoundData ;
 token.transfer(owner,cost);
}
```

}

Comment: The error and the code doesn't seem to match. Maybe post the exact code along with the error in the description.

Comment: Please update the question with the correct code and delete the answer with the code, since its not an answer

Comment: Hi phil! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Please, always include source code as text it makes testing much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. `priceFeed.latestRoundData()` returns 5 data points:

```js
uint80 roundID,  
int price,  
uint startedAt,
uint timeStamp,
uint80 answeredInRound
```

I'm assuming you want just the price which you can isolate with a line like this in your code:
`(,int price,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();`

2. `price` is of type `int` while your `cost` and `_payAmount` variables are of type `uint`. I recommend changing them to type `int` to match the feeds type. If you really need to you can typecast the price variable to `uint` or your `cost` and `_payAmount` variables to `int` with a line like this:
   `int cost = int(_payAmount) * 6 * price;`